# squirrelmail unable to send / receive mail

Tags: server, email, postfix

I am configuring my own mail server for my domain after installing dovecot, postfix and squirrelmail I am stuck again.

This time when i try to sendmail to an outside e-mail address I get this error :

```
Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable
550 5.1.1 <xxxx@gmail.com>: Recipient address rejected: gmail.com
```

If I try to send mail to the user@mydomain I don't get a error but I don't receive anything.

What can be the problem, please request more details if you need some.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a couple of things.

First, see if port 25 is blocked by your ISP.  If it is, change your configuration to use port 587.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2010514

Second, this person found that commenting out a couple lines does the trick:

```
#default_transport = error
#relay_transport = error
```

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1045220